# Will a different charger be a problem?

Tags: charger

I have a 36V cordless lawnmower whose charger has died. A replacement charger costs $120 (!), which makes it not worth buying. The charger is 36V 800ma.

I can buy a charger for an eBike that is rated at 36V 2A for $20. I am comfortable swapping the plug from the dead charger to the replacement one.

The insides of the mower don't seem to have any regulating circuitry. The mower batteries are lead acid.

How likely would I be to have problems if I buy the replacement charger, swap the plugs and try using it? I'm not worried about long term problems - I'll probably dump the mower if I can't make it work - but I don't want to do anything dangerous.

Comment: Battery chemistry?

Comment: Your question doesn't say what the battery chemistry is and what chemistry the charger is for.

Comment: The mower batteries are lead. There are a few chargers out there. Do they have to be specifically for lead?

Comment: @DJClayworth It's very important that the charger be made for the correct chemistry of battery. If you tried to use a lead-acid charger for a lithium battery, it would blow up the battery in short order, and a NiCd charger on a lead-acid battery would never stop charging it.

Comment: That might be an excellent answer, in case there are more people like me out there.

Comment: if the plug on your existing charger has only two contacts it should be piossible to substitude a new charger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very important that the charger be made for the correct chemistry of battery. If you tried to use a lead-acid charger for a lithium battery, it would blow up the battery in short order, and a lithium charger on a lead-acid battery would refuse to charge it at all.

That said, a generic lead-acid battery charger would probably work perfectly well.